# calculating cross-correlation for a 10000 by 10000 matrix

Tags: matlab, bigdata, autocorrelation

I am using the xcorr as bellow

```
simM=xcorr(data,10,'normalized');
```

Here data is a 1200 by 1200 double  and the the output i.e. simM is a 21*1440000 double . Now i want to calculate for more values but my .   systems ram is only 64 GB. For data bigger than 1500 by 1500  the system is giving out of memory error. Which is acceptable. So according to some of the answers i have read in MATLAB community i found out splitting the  matrix is an option. But can you please describe how can i do that.
For 1100 by 1100 samples the time consumed by my system is 147 seconds if possible can you suggest a way to improve the speed.

Comment: This isn't a problem I've directly encountered, but if your matrix has lots of zeroes in it, it may be possible to do the calculations using [sparse matrices](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html). I can't help you with how they work or any troubleshooting, but for arrays with lots of zeroes, they reduce the memory needed.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience, but my data cant be zeros, I have to plot that data in my next steps.

Answer (score 1):

loop on the columns of d

```
for i=1:1200
  for j=1:1200
    simulation((i-1)*1200+j)=xcorr(d(:,i),d(:,j),10,'normalize');
  end
end
```

for speed convert your double to single , (single(d)) it reduces ram usage and calculation time, and you could use parfor or  gpu computing for further speed up the for loop.

```
d=single(d);
d=gpuArray(d);
...
```